# Objective-C – Doing NSMutableArray operations in a class but return NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm sorry for the little confusing title but say I have a class with an interface that looks like this:

```
@interface Class : NSObject {

    NSArray *items;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *items;

@end
```

In the impementation I actually want to do some adding operations thus using `NSMutableArray` and then the user using the class should be able to retrieve the data as an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare mutable array as instance variable, declare the property as readonly NSArray and overwrite the getter.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {

    NSMutableArray *mutableItems;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *items;

@end

@implementation SomeClass

- (NSArray *)items {
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableItems];
}

@end
```

Comment: But wouldn't he (in his implementation of `SomeClass`) still receive warnings if he attempts to use any of the `NSMutableArray` methods like `addObject:`, since the compiler doesn't know it's internally an `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: there will be no problem since he will be able to use the array as instance variable, not as class's property (`mutableItems` vs. `self.items`). I also understood that use should get the `NSArray` while, the class itself inside would be able to modify the array itself.

Comment: But if he (in `SomeClass.m`) were to call: `[mutableItems addObject:obj]` this would result in a compiler warning, as the compiler thinks (not unreasonably) that the `mutableItems` is actually an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

There is little reason not to just return an NSMutableArray from a method declared as returning an NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you don't want the user to change the array you can just do it like this:

```
@interface Class : NSObject 
- (NSArray*) items;
@end

@implementation Class
{
   NSMutableArray *items;
}

// Allocate 'items' somewhere in your init method

- (NSArray*)items
{
  return items;
}

@end
```

Comment: This only *indicates* to the user that the array should not be changed (since they don't know it's actually a mutable subclass), it doesn't actually prevent changes from occurring.

Comment: That is true, but otoh Objective-C lives from conventions the user should adhere to rather than preventing strange things to happen. However, I'm willing to change the implementation so the user wouldn't even try ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining a property for your instance variable, you could simply define the variable as the type you want it to be:

```
@interface Class : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *items;
}
```

And use it as an `NSMutableArray`:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self == [super init])) {
        items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Don't forget to release me!
    } 
}
```

But then in your interface, define a getter method that returns an `NSArray`:

```
- (NSArray *)items;
```

And implement it as such:

```
- (NSArray *)items {
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:items];
}
```